# HTML Button direct to others link didn't work on Github Pages

Tags: html, github, button, hyperlink

Here is the problem, so I'm trying to deploy my website on Github Pages. It works, until I try to click my button which is when it got clicked will redirect to wa.me. It does redirect to wa.me when I try it in localhost, but it didn't work on my Github Pages. It came out looks like this

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline"
                  type="button"
                  onclick="window.open('https:wa.me/085155448143?text=Halo%20saya%20ingin%20mengetahui%20info%20lebih%20lanjut%20tentang%20kursus%20di%20Auto%20Mitsuda', '_blank')">
            Chat Kami
          </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `//` in your href.

should be `onclick="window.open('https://wa.me/085155448143?text=Halo%20saya%20ingin%20mengetahui%20info%20lebih%20lanjut%20tentang%20kursus%20di%20Auto%20Mitsuda', '_blank')">`
`

Comment: but if i use double slash, it will commented the line

Comment: nvm, it works bro. thank you so muchh~

Comment: Great! ヽ(´▽`)/  ....